# Is it possible to mix literal words and tags in NLTK regex

Tags: python, nltk

I'm experimenting with NLTK to help me parse some text. As an example I have:

```
1 Robins Drive owned by Gregg S. Smith was sold to TeStER, LLC of 494 Bridge Avenue, Suite 101-308, Sheltville AZ 02997 for $27,000.00.
```

using:

```
words =pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence))
```

I get:

```
[('1', 'CD'), ('Robins', 'NNP'), ('Drive', 'NNP'), ('owned', 'VBN'), ('by', 'IN'), ('Gregg', 'NNP'), ('S.', 'NNP'), ('Smith', 'NNP'), ('was', 'VBD'), ('sold', 'VBN'), ('to', 'TO'), ('TeStER', 'NNP'), (',', ','), ('LLC', 'NNP'), ('of', 'IN'), ('494', 'CD'), ('Bridge', 'NNP'), ('Avenue', 'NNP'), (',', ','), ('Suite', 'NNP'), ('101-308', 'CD'), (',', ','), ('Sheltville', 'NNP'), ('AZ', 'NNP'), ('02997', 'CD'), ('for', 'IN'), ('$', '$'), ('27,000.00', 'CD'), ('.', '.')]
```

Assuming I want to extract the role of 'owner' (Gregg S. Smith), Is there a way to mix and match literals and tags perhaps of a format something like:

```
'owned by{<NP>+}'
```

There was a previous discussion of this at [Mixing words and PoS tags in NLTK parser grammars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755638/mixing-words-and-pos-tags-in-nltk-parser-grammars), but I'm not sure I understood the provided answer. Is this possible, and if so could you provide a code example.

Comment: Well, you should tokenize your initial string and attach string representation of PoS to it. Then just write rules according to your token+PoS format.

Comment: Would you mind giving an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you combine each word and tag and then use `RegEx` to look for certain sequences of PoS tags you can get the results you are looking for.

for example, using the `words` variable you have defined

```
joined = ' '.join([w+"<"+t+">" for w,t in words])
```

would produce

```
'1<CD> Robins<NNP> Drive<NNP> owned<VBN> by<IN> Gregg<NNP> S.<NNP> Smith<NNP> was<VBD> sold<VBN> to<TO> TeStER<NNP> ,<,> LLC<NNP> of<IN> 494<CD> Bridge<NNP> Avenue<NNP> ,<,> Suite<NNP> 101-308<CD> ,<,> Sheltville<NNP> AZ<NNP> 02997<CD> for<IN> $<$> 27,000.00<CD> .<.>'
```

Then you have to create a regular expression to find the sequence you are looking for depending on word/tag context.

For example, using the python RegEx module `re`

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.match(r'.*owned<VBN> by<IN>.*?<NNP>', joined)
>>> m.group(0)
'1<CD> Robins<NNP> Drive<NNP> owned<VBN> by<IN> Gregg<NNP>'
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nathan, I will check it out.